# Using sqlchemy in Pyqt, is it possible?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pyqt

Hi i am new to Pyqt and i am wondering if it is possible to have goodness of sqlalchemy e.g. connection pooling and managing, abstracting away all the menial low level details?

Comment: Why should the part of your application using SQLAlchemy suddenly break because some other part uses PyQt?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Camelot. http://www.python-camelot.com/